# Extract binary value from continuous variable

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, linearization

I have a continuous variable $c$ which has value in between $[-R, +R]$.

I want to create a boolean variable $x$ and,

$x = 1$ when $c = 1.0$ otherwise $x = 0$

In more general form:

$x = 1$ when $c \in [-k, +k]$ otherwise $x = 0$ here $[-k, +k]$ is a new range inside $[-R, +R]$